# Run validator less often, when leaving field, rather than as user types in Vaadin 8 Binder

Tags: java, validation, data-binding, vaadin, vaadin8

In [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 8, the [new `Binder` feature](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html) can have one or more validators attached to a field. These validators run immediately, as a user types in a TextField for example.

Is there a way to avoid running the validators so often, instead running only when the focus leaves the user such as when the user presses Tab to move to another field?

Answer (score 8):

The default behavior of the TextField when to trigger a value change event has changed in Vaadin 8. But if you set the `ValueChangeMode` to `BLUR` it will work as you know from Vaadin 7.

```
// BLUR gives the old Vaadin 7 behavior, LAZY is default.
textField.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.BLUR);
```

From the Vaadin 8 sources:

```
/**
 * Fires a server-side event when the field loses focus.
 */
BLUR,

/**
 * On every user event, schedule a server-side event after a defined
 * interval, cancelling the currently-scheduled event if any. This is a good
 * choice if you want to, for instance, wait for a small break in the user's
 * typing before sending the event.
 */
LAZY
```

The validation is automatically done after the value change. With the modification of the `ValueChangeMode` you can run the value change event and the validation less often.

Comment: The timeout can be set by `textField.setValueChangeTimeout(timeoutInMs)`. Default setting is 400 ms.